# OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants []

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, geopandas, shapely, conda-forge

After executing this line `from shapely.geometry import Line` I get issues on this

OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants [].

So, I created a new environment in anaconda and set priority to conda-forge so that I wouldn't be mixing packages from different channels as mentioned here:  https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#how-to-fix-it

However, as I install geopandas and run this line in the interpreter,

```
from shapely.geometry import Line
```

the same error comes out.

- I have tried this: https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#how-to-fix-it
- I tried setting this: export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib as mentioned on related issues here.

Steps done:

1. Create a new environment GIS
2. Set channel priority to conda-forge
3. installed geopandas
4. Tried executing `from shapely.geometry import Line` however, I still get the same error.

This is my environment now `(conda list)`:

```
(GIS) bash-3.2$ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               h75728bb_2    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            he1c11cd_1002    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1    conda-forge
cfitsio                   3.470                h389770f_1    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.65.3               h22ea746_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5             h6de7cb9_1003    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.6            py37h39889d8_4    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            h6b1039f_1001    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h24853df_1    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5             h1de35cc_1002    conda-forge
gdal                      2.4.2            py37h39889d8_4    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.7.2                h6de7cb9_1    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.5.1                h83de174_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h46ab8bc_1002    conda-forge
giflib                    5.1.7                h01d97ff_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3            h9d45998_1002    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            hf3c6af0_1002    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_h0cbb7df_1100    conda-forge
icu                       64.2                 h6de7cb9_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
json-c                    0.13.1            h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.10            h6659575_1005    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.3            hcfa6398_1001    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0               11_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0               11_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.65.3               h16faf7d_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    8.0.0                         4    conda-forge
libcxxabi                 8.0.0                         4    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.20.2            hae55d67_1000    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20170329      hcfe32e1_1001    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             h6de7cb9_1006    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.4.2                hf77bb78_4    conda-forge
libgfortran               3.0.1                         0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              h01d97ff_1005    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             hed7d534_1010    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0               11_openblas    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.2             h1a02027_1002    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.6                hd44dcd8_6    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h2573ce8_0    conda-forge
libpq                     11.5                 h756f0eb_0    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.9.0                h6de7cb9_1    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            he369b6e_1029    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.2                hcdc9a53_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            hd08fb8f_1003    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h12c6b28_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             h6de7cb9_1001    conda-forge
munch                     2.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1               h0a44026_1002    conda-forge
numpy                     1.17.0           py37h6b0580a_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.3.1                hc1feee7_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1c               h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.0           py37h86efe34_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.41              h0a44026_1003    conda-forge
pip                       19.2.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.38.0            h01d97ff_1003    conda-forge
poppler                   0.67.0               hd5eb092_7    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.9                         1    conda-forge
postgresql                11.5                 h25afefd_0    conda-forge
proj4                     6.1.0                h2cc77ee_2    conda-forge
pyproj                    2.2.1            py37h804dea5_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                h93065d6_1    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.2                     py_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.0                  hcfe32e1_0    conda-forge
rtree                     0.8.3           py37h666c49c_1002    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4           py37h0567c5e_1006    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.29.0               hb7d70f7_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             h2573ce8_1002    conda-forge
tzcode                    2019a             h01d97ff_1002    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2             hbda6038_1004    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h01d97ff_1005    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.0                ha9f0a20_0    conda-forge
```

Details about my system `(conda info)`:

(GIS) bash-3.2$ conda info

```
     active environment : GIS
    active env location : /Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/jacob/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/jacob/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.10
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /Users/jacob/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/jacob/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/jacob/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/jacob/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.10 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/18.7.0 OSX/10.14.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`conda info -s` gives:

```
(GIS) bash-3.2$ conda info -s
sys.version: 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
...
sys.prefix: /Users/jacob/anaconda3
sys.executable: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/python
conda location: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda
conda-build: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-build
conda-convert: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-convert
conda-debug: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-debug
conda-develop: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-develop
conda-env: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
conda-index: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-index
conda-inspect: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-inspect
conda-metapackage: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-metapackage
conda-render: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-render
conda-server: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-server
conda-skeleton: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-skeleton
conda-verify: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda-verify
user site dirs: 

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: GIS
CONDA_EXE: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PREFIX: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS
CONDA_PREFIX_1: /Users/jacob/anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (GIS) 
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin/python
CONDA_ROOT: /Users/jacob/anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 2
PATH: /Users/jacob/anaconda3/bin:/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/bin:/Users/jacob/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/git/bin:/sw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/netcdf/4.6.3_1/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/mpich3/include:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Users/jacob/Desktop/WRF4/ncl/ncl_6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/opt/inetutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/jacob/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

and `cat .condarc`:

```
(GIS) bash-3.2$ cat .condarc
ssl_verify: true
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
channel_priority: strict
```

the error from the python prompt is still the same:

`from shapely.geometry import Line`

```
Last login: Sat Aug 10 23:00:22 on ttys000
-bash: HOME: command not found
/Users/jacob/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
(base) Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:~ jacob$ /Users/jacob/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 14:38:56) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from shapely.geometry import Line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
  File "/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
  File "/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/coords.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 113, in <module>
    free = load_dll('c').free
  File "/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 56, in load_dll
    libname, fallbacks or []))
OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants [].
```

List of files inside ../GIS/lib:

```
(base) Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:lib jacob$ pwd
/Users/jacob/anaconda3/envs/GIS/lib
(base) Jacobs-MacBook-Pro:lib jacob$ ls
GNU.Gettext.dll             libicui18n.dylib
Tk.icns                 libicuio.64.2.dylib
Tk.tiff                 libicuio.64.dylib
_int.so                 libicuio.dylib
adminpack.so                libicutest.64.2.dylib
amcheck.so              libicutest.64.dylib
ascii_and_mic.so            libicutest.dylib
auth_delay.so               libicutu.64.2.dylib
auto_explain.so             libicutu.64.dylib
autoinc.so              libicutu.dylib
bloom.so                libicuuc.64.2.dylib
btree_gin.so                libicuuc.64.dylib
btree_gist.so               libicuuc.dylib
cairo                   libintl.8.dylib
charset.alias               libintl.a
citext.so               libintl.dylib
cmake                   libjpeg.9.dylib
cube.so                 libjpeg.a
cyrillic_and_mic.so         libjpeg.dylib
dblink.so               libjson-c.4.dylib
dict_int.so             libjson-c.a
dict_snowball.so            libjson-c.dylib
dict_xsyn.so                libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
earthdistance.so            libk5crypto.3.dylib
engines-1.1             libk5crypto.dylib
euc2004_sjis2004.so         libkadm5clnt.dylib
euc_cn_and_mic.so           libkadm5clnt_mit.11.0.dylib
euc_jp_and_sjis.so          libkadm5clnt_mit.11.dylib
euc_kr_and_mic.so           libkadm5clnt_mit.dylib
euc_tw_and_big5.so          libkadm5srv.dylib
file_fdw.so             libkadm5srv_mit.11.0.dylib
fuzzystrmatch.so            libkadm5srv_mit.11.dylib
gettext                 libkadm5srv_mit.dylib
girepository-1.0            libkdb5.9.0.dylib
glib-2.0                libkdb5.9.dylib
hstore.so               libkdb5.dylib
icu                 libkea.1.4.10.dylib
insert_username.so          libkea.1.4.dylib
isn.so                  libkea.dylib
itcl4.1.2               libkmlbase.1.3.0.dylib
krb5                    libkmlbase.1.dylib
latin2_and_win1250.so           libkmlbase.dylib
latin_and_mic.so            libkmlconvenience.1.3.0.dylib
libasprintf.0.dylib         libkmlconvenience.1.dylib
libasprintf.a               libkmlconvenience.dylib
libasprintf.dylib           libkmldom.1.3.0.dylib
libblas.3.dylib             libkmldom.1.dylib
libblas.dylib               libkmldom.dylib
libboost_atomic.a           libkmlengine.1.3.0.dylib
libboost_atomic.dylib           libkmlengine.1.dylib
libboost_chrono.a           libkmlengine.dylib
libboost_chrono.dylib           libkmlregionator.1.3.0.dylib
libboost_container.a            libkmlregionator.1.dylib
libboost_container.dylib        libkmlregionator.dylib
libboost_context.a          libkmlxsd.1.3.0.dylib
libboost_context.dylib          libkmlxsd.1.dylib
libboost_contract.a         libkmlxsd.dylib
libboost_contract.dylib         libkrad.0.0.dylib
libboost_coroutine.a            libkrad.0.dylib
libboost_coroutine.dylib        libkrad.dylib
libboost_date_time.a            libkrb5.3.3.dylib
libboost_date_time.dylib        libkrb5.3.dylib
libboost_exception.a            libkrb5.dylib
libboost_fiber.a            libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
libboost_fiber.dylib            libkrb5support.1.dylib
libboost_filesystem.a           libkrb5support.dylib
libboost_filesystem.dylib       liblapack.3.dylib
libboost_graph.a            liblapack.dylib
libboost_graph.dylib            liblz4.1.8.3.dylib
libboost_iostreams.a            liblz4.1.dylib
libboost_iostreams.dylib        liblz4.a
libboost_locale.a           liblz4.dylib
libboost_locale.dylib           liblzma.5.dylib
libboost_log.a              liblzma.a
libboost_log.dylib          liblzma.dylib
libboost_log_setup.a            libmenu.6.dylib
libboost_log_setup.dylib        libmenu.a
libboost_math_c99.a         libmenu.dylib
libboost_math_c99.dylib         libmenuw.6.dylib
libboost_math_c99f.a            libmenuw.a
libboost_math_c99f.dylib        libmenuw.dylib
libboost_math_c99l.a            libmfhdf.0.dylib
libboost_math_c99l.dylib        libmfhdf.a
libboost_math_tr1.a         libmfhdf.dylib
libboost_math_tr1.dylib         libminizip.dylib
libboost_math_tr1f.a            libncurses++.a
libboost_math_tr1f.dylib        libncurses++w.a
libboost_math_tr1l.a            libncurses.6.dylib
libboost_math_tr1l.dylib        libncurses.a
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a     libncurses.dylib
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.dylib     libncursesw.6.dylib
libboost_program_options.a      libncursesw.a
libboost_program_options.dylib      libncursesw.dylib
libboost_random.a           libnetcdf.13.dylib
libboost_random.dylib           libnetcdf.a
libboost_regex.a            libnetcdf.dylib
libboost_regex.dylib            libnetcdf.settings
libboost_serialization.a        libopenblas.0.dylib
libboost_serialization.dylib        libopenblasp-r0.3.6.dylib
libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.a     libopenjp2.2.3.1.dylib
libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.dylib libopenjp2.7.dylib
libboost_stacktrace_basic.a     libopenjp2.a
libboost_stacktrace_basic.dylib     libopenjp2.dylib
libboost_stacktrace_noop.a      libpanel.6.dylib
libboost_stacktrace_noop.dylib      libpanel.a
libboost_system.a           libpanel.dylib
libboost_system.dylib           libpanelw.6.dylib
libboost_test_exec_monitor.a        libpanelw.a
libboost_thread.a           libpanelw.dylib
libboost_thread.dylib           libpcre.1.dylib
libboost_timer.a            libpcre.a
libboost_timer.dylib            libpcre.dylib
libboost_type_erasure.a         libpcrecpp.0.dylib
libboost_type_erasure.dylib     libpcrecpp.a
libboost_unit_test_framework.a      libpcrecpp.dylib
libboost_unit_test_framework.dylib  libpcreposix.0.dylib
libboost_wave.a             libpcreposix.a
libboost_wave.dylib         libpcreposix.dylib
libboost_wserialization.a       libpgcommon.a
libboost_wserialization.dylib       libpgfeutils.a
libbz2.1.0.8.dylib          libpgport.a
libbz2.a                libpgtypes.3.11.dylib
libbz2.dylib                libpgtypes.3.dylib
libc++.1.0.dylib            libpgtypes.a
libc++.1.dylib              libpgtypes.dylib
libc++.a                libpixman-1.0.dylib
libc++.dylib                libpixman-1.a
libc++abi.1.0.dylib         libpixman-1.dylib
libc++abi.1.dylib           libpng.a
libc++abi.a             libpng.dylib
libc++abi.dylib             libpng16.16.dylib
libc++experimental.a            libpng16.a
libc++fs.a              libpng16.dylib
libcairo-gobject.2.dylib        libpoppler-cpp.0.5.0.dylib
libcairo-gobject.a          libpoppler-cpp.0.dylib
libcairo-gobject.dylib          libpoppler-cpp.dylib
libcairo-script-interpreter.2.dylib libpoppler-glib.8.9.0.dylib
libcairo-script-interpreter.a       libpoppler-glib.8.dylib
libcairo-script-interpreter.dylib   libpoppler-glib.dylib
libcairo.2.dylib            libpoppler.78.0.0.dylib
libcairo.a              libpoppler.78.dylib
libcairo.dylib              libpoppler.dylib
libcblas.3.dylib            libpq.5.11.dylib
libcblas.dylib              libpq.5.dylib
libcfitsio.8.3.47.dylib         libpq.a
libcfitsio.8.dylib          libpq.dylib
libcfitsio.a                libpqwalreceiver.so
libcfitsio.dylib            libproj.15.dylib
libcharset.1.dylib          libproj.a
libcharset.a                libproj.dylib
libcharset.dylib            libpython3.7m.a
libcom_err.3.0.dylib            libpython3.7m.dylib
libcom_err.3.dylib          libquadmath.0.dylib
libcom_err.dylib            libquadmath.dylib
libcrypto.1.1.dylib         libreadline.8.0.dylib
libcrypto.dylib             libreadline.8.dylib
libcurl.4.dylib             libreadline.a
libcurl.a               libreadline.dylib
libcurl.dylib               libspatialindex.5.0.0.dylib
libdap.25.dylib             libspatialindex.5.dylib
libdap.a                libspatialindex.dylib
libdap.dylib                libspatialindex_c.5.0.0.dylib
libdapclient.6.dylib            libspatialindex_c.5.dylib
libdapclient.a              libspatialindex_c.dylib
libdapclient.dylib          libspatialite.7.dylib
libdapserver.7.dylib            libspatialite.dylib
libdapserver.a              libsqlite3.0.dylib
libdapserver.dylib          libsqlite3.a
libdf.0.dylib               libsqlite3.dylib
libdf.a                 libssh2.1.0.1.dylib
libdf.dylib             libssh2.1.dylib
libecpg.6.11.dylib          libssh2.a
libecpg.6.dylib             libssh2.dylib
libecpg.a               libssl.1.1.dylib
libecpg.dylib               libssl.dylib
libecpg_compat.3.11.dylib       libtcl8.6.dylib
libecpg_compat.3.dylib          libtclstub8.6.a
libecpg_compat.a            libtest-types.a
libecpg_compat.dylib            libtiff.5.dylib
libedit.0.dylib             libtiff.a
libedit.a               libtiff.dylib
libedit.dylib               libtiffxx.5.dylib
libexpat.1.6.7.dylib            libtiffxx.a
libexpat.1.dylib            libtiffxx.dylib
libexpat.a              libtinfo.6.dylib
libexpat.dylib              libtinfo.a
libffi.6.dylib              libtinfo.dylib
libffi.a                libtinfow.6.dylib
libffi.dylib                libtinfow.a
libfontconfig.1.dylib           libtinfow.dylib
libfontconfig.a             libtk8.6.dylib
libfontconfig.dylib         libtkstub8.6.a
libform.6.dylib             libtz.a
libform.a               liburiparser.dylib
libform.dylib               libverto.0.0.dylib
libformw.6.dylib            libverto.0.dylib
libformw.a              libverto.dylib
libformw.dylib              libxerces-c-3.2.dylib
libfreetype.6.dylib         libxerces-c.dylib
libfreetype.a               libxml2.2.dylib
libfreetype.dylib           libxml2.dylib
libfreexl.1.dylib           libz.1.2.11.dylib
libfreexl.a             libz.1.dylib
libfreexl.dylib             libz.a
libgcc_s.1.dylib            libz.dylib
libgcc_s_ppc64.1.dylib          libzstd.1.4.0.dylib
libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib         libzstd.1.dylib
libgdal.20.dylib            libzstd.a
libgdal.a               libzstd.dylib
libgdal.dylib               lo.so
libgeos-3.7.2.dylib         ltree.so
libgeos.dylib               mod_spatialite.7.so
libgeos_c.1.dylib           mod_spatialite.so
libgeos_c.dylib             moddatetime.so
libgeotiff.5.0.0.dylib          openjpeg-2.3
libgeotiff.5.dylib          pageinspect.so
libgeotiff.dylib            passwordcheck.so
libgettextlib-0.19.8.1.dylib        pg_buffercache.so
libgettextlib.dylib         pg_freespacemap.so
libgettextpo.0.dylib            pg_prewarm.so
libgettextpo.a              pg_stat_statements.so
libgettextpo.dylib          pg_trgm.so
libgettextsrc-0.19.8.1.dylib        pg_visibility.so
libgettextsrc.dylib         pgcrypto.so
libgfortran.3.dylib         pgoutput.so
libgfortran.dylib           pgrowlocks.so
libgif.a                pgstattuple.so
libgif.so               pgxml.so
libgif.so.7             pgxs
libgif.so.7.1.0             pkgconfig
libgio-2.0.0.dylib          plpgsql.so
libgio-2.0.dylib            postgres_fdw.so
libglib-2.0.0.dylib         python3.7
libglib-2.0.dylib           refint.so
libgmodule-2.0.0.dylib          seg.so
libgmodule-2.0.dylib            sqlite3.25.3
libgobject-2.0.0.dylib          sslinfo.so
libgobject-2.0.dylib            tablefunc.so
libgomp.1.dylib             tcl8
libgomp.dylib               tcl8.6
libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib        tclConfig.sh
libgssapi_krb5.2.dylib          tclooConfig.sh
libgssapi_krb5.dylib            tcn.so
libgssrpc.4.2.dylib         tdbc1.1.0
libgssrpc.4.dylib           tdbcmysql1.1.0
libgssrpc.dylib             tdbcodbc1.1.0
libgthread-2.0.0.dylib          tdbcpostgres1.1.0
libgthread-2.0.dylib            terminfo
libhdf4.settings            terminfo.c~
libhdf5.103.dylib           test_decoding.so
libhdf5.a               thread2.8.4
libhdf5.dylib               timetravel.so
libhdf5.settings            tk8.6
libhdf5_cpp.103.dylib           tkConfig.sh
libhdf5_cpp.a               tsm_system_rows.so
libhdf5_cpp.dylib           tsm_system_time.so
libhdf5_fortran.a           unaccent.so
libhdf5_hl.100.dylib            utf8_and_ascii.so
libhdf5_hl.a                utf8_and_big5.so
libhdf5_hl.dylib            utf8_and_cyrillic.so
libhdf5_hl_cpp.100.dylib        utf8_and_euc2004.so
libhdf5_hl_cpp.a            utf8_and_euc_cn.so
libhdf5_hl_cpp.dylib            utf8_and_euc_jp.so
libhdf5_hl_fortran.a            utf8_and_euc_kr.so
libhdf5hl_fortran.a         utf8_and_euc_tw.so
libhistory.8.0.dylib            utf8_and_gb18030.so
libhistory.8.dylib          utf8_and_gbk.so
libhistory.a                utf8_and_iso8859.so
libhistory.dylib            utf8_and_iso8859_1.so
libiconv.2.dylib            utf8_and_johab.so
libiconv.a              utf8_and_sjis.so
libiconv.dylib              utf8_and_sjis2004.so
libicudata.64.2.dylib           utf8_and_uhc.so
libicudata.64.dylib         utf8_and_win.so
libicudata.dylib            uuid-ossp.so
libicui18n.64.2.dylib           xml2Conf.sh
libicui18n.64.dylib
```

I created a new environment and set conda-forge to priority and set this `conda config --set channel_priority strict`.  I am not sure why this is still happening.

It seems that a lot of osx users come across this problem.

Line from shapely.geometry should have been imported.

Comment: Note: the import you are trying does not exist, it should be `from shapely.geometry import LineString`. Although I suppose that is not the reason you see that error. Can you open an issue at https://github.com/conda-forge/shapely-feedstock ?